# Multiple Order By On Same Column in Laravel ,Does Any Way Exist?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want Data From Both Queries One After Another

```
->when($todayDate, function ($query) use ($todayDate) {
       $query->whereDate('startdate', '>=', $todayDate)->orderBy('batches.startdate', 'desc');
})->when($todayDate, function ($query) use ($todayDate) {
       $query->whereDate('startdate', '<=', $todayDate)->orderBy('batches.startdate', 'desc');
})
```

Comment: I dont understand. How would this differ from just using `orderBy('batches.startdate', 'desc')` without specifying a `whereDate` ?

Comment: $todayDate = date('Y-m-d');

Comment: Yes but you are getting all dates before (and including) that date  **and** all dates after (and including) that date. That's just all dates regardless of what that date is. Is your intention to just get the data on that date only? Or data from all dates? Or something else that you've not specified?

Comment: i want to get data which have batches first  followed by data which batches have been expired

Comment: You needed to provide more information for your question because as it is now it looks like a strange request

Comment: i have answered you can check the whole query there

Answer (score 0):

```
`$todayDate = now()->toDateString();

$upcoming = DB::table('table_name')
->when($todayDate, function ($query) use ($todayDate) {
    $query->whereDate('startdate', '>=', $todayDate)
        ->orderBy('batches.startdate', 'desc');
});

$past = DB::table('table_name')
->when($todayDate, function ($query) use ($todayDate) {
    $query->whereDate('startdate', '<=', $todayDate)
        ->orderBy('batches.startdate', 'desc');
});

$results = $upcoming->union($past)->get();'

'->when($todayDate, function ($query) use ($todayDate) { 
$query->orderBy('startdate', 'desc')
     ->orderByRaw("startdate >= '{$todayDate}' desc");
})`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$packages1 = Package::select('packages.*')->join('package_prices', 'packages.id', '=', 'package_prices.package_id')
                ->Join('package_itineraries', 'packages.id', '=', 'package_itineraries.package_id')
                ->leftJoin('batches', 'packages.id', '=', 'batches.package_id')
                ->when($states, function ($query) use ($states) {
                    $states = Collection::make(explode(",", $states));
                    $query->whereIn('state_id', $states);
                })
                ->when($countries, function ($query) use ($countries) {
                    $countries = Collection::make(explode(",", $countries));
                    $query->whereIn('country_id', $countries);
                })

                ->when($difficulty, function ($query) use ($difficulty) {
                    $difficulty = Collection::make(explode(",", $difficulty));
                    $query->whereIn('trek_difficulty_id', $difficulty);
                })

                ->when($category, function ($query) use ($category) {
                    $query->where('category_id', $category);
                })
                ->when($prices, function ($query) use ($prices) {
                    $query->priceBetween($prices);
                })
                ->when($batches, function ($query) use ($batches) {
                    $query->batchesBetween($batches);
                })
                ->when($duration, function ($query) use ($duration) {
                    $query->DurationBetween($duration);
                })
                ->when($startingLocations, function ($query) use ($startingLocations) {
                    $query->Startinglocations($startingLocations);
                })
                ->when($columnName, function ($query) use ($columnName, $columnSortOrder) {
                    if ($columnName == "price") {
                        $query->where('package_prices.is_default', 1)->orderBy('package_prices.price', $columnSortOrder);
                    } elseif ($columnName == "duration") {
                        $query->orderBy('package_itineraries.duration', $columnSortOrder);
                    }
                    $query->orderBy($columnName, $columnSortOrder);
                })
                ->when($todayDate, function ($query) use ($todayDate) {
                    $query->whereDate('batches.startdate', '>=', $todayDate)->orderBy('batches.startdate', 'asc');
                });
```

Comment: my single Query is so large ,with union i am making two query $packages1 and $packages 2 , and uniting them,  $packages = $packages1->union($packages2)->get();

Answer (score 0):

This is How we can do without Union

```
 $case = "CASE WHEN batches.startdate >= CURDATE() THEN 1 ELSE 2 END";


 ->orderByRaw($case)
                ->orderBy('batches.startdate')
```

Answer (score -1):

In Laravel, you can use the union() method to combine the results of two queries. Here's an example:

```
$todayDate = date('Y-m-d');

$query1 = DB::table('table_name')
    ->when($todayDate, function ($query) use ($todayDate) {
        $query->whereDate('startdate', '>=', $todayDate)
            ->orderBy('batches.startdate', 'desc');
    });

$query2 = DB::table('table_name')
    ->when($todayDate, function ($query) use ($todayDate) {
        $query->whereDate('startdate', '<=', $todayDate)
            ->orderBy('batches.startdate', 'desc');
    });

$results = $query1->union($query2)->get();
```

Comment: unoin is working but my query is large , so i have to unite two large query that is taking time

Comment: Use indexing: Indexing can greatly improve the performance of your queries by allowing the database to quickly find the relevant data

and you can also set a limit